# Editing attribute using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, editing

I'm trying to automate a simple repetitive task on QGIS. I have some shapefiles with varying number of features in a layer and about 10 different attributes for each feature. I need to add the same string value ("negative") to one of these attributes, over and over again. Copy, paste works but since I want to sharpen my Python scripting skills I'd like to achieve this by creating a simple Python script.

I'm able to print values of attributes using something like this;

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():

    print("{acreage} acres in {name}".format(name=feature['fieldname'],acreage=feature['acreage']))
```

But I'm stuck at this point. How would I write "negative" to the attribute "acreage"? I tried set.Feature() but it just didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not far away, just some lines of code:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
fts = lyr.getFeatures()
lyr.startEditing()
for f in fts:
    f['myfield']='mystring'
    lyr.updateFeature(f)
lyr.commitChanges() #ends the editing session and commit all changes
```

for some good examples see:
https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/
or
https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! I wish I asked earlier, spent all day trying to get this working. I already got to the point using and combining examples on anitagraser.com . Thank you so much again!

Comment: If it works, then you can accept the answer  - just click on the accept icon. Thank you

Comment: i didn't know about this, done, thanks a bunch again!

Comment: Can I ask another question? What if I want to modify this script so it only writes to the empty fields and skips the ones with already a string in them? I tried some if else statements but couldn't get it to work. Could you help me improve this script? Thanks a lot

Comment: in python just use: "if not f['myfield']:" which will proof if myfield is empty...

Comment: thank you, so I'm trying this;

`lyr = iface.activeLayer()
fts = lyr.getFeatures()
lyr.startEditing()
for f in fts:
    if not f['POSITIVE']:
        f['MARK']='NEGATIVE'
        lyr.updateFeature(f)
lyr.commitChanges()`

And get this;

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
KeyError: 'POSITIVE'`

what should I change in my code?

Comment: if not f['POSITIVE']: means that there is a fieldname 'POSITIVE'. The error says, that there is no field called 'POSITIVE'. I suppose the code should be like this: if not f['MARK']: ... which means the field MARK is empty...

Comment: Thank you again. I just couldn't get it to work. I added the line if not f['MARK']:'POSITIVE' which removed the error above but it changes all the cells, even the ones marked with POSITIVE. I know it's hard to guess without seeing it in action but any further input will be appreciated. Thanks again.